Archives not showing in Archive Manager in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.7.6 for a .NET MAUI project [ .net 6]
When attempting to publish my .NET MAUI project, which utilizes the .NET 6 workload, I encountered an issue. Specifically, when selecting the Android emulator or a physical device as the target platform, the archive is not being displayed in the archive manager. Instead, it is being created in the local path [C:\Users\SMR\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Archives]. Consequently, I am unable to distribute the app or provide a test release. This problem persists even when targeting the iOS platform. I would greatly appreciate assistance in resolving this issue.
Archive Manager:

And also as you can see in the above image, I am not able to see my projects under the current solution section which in turn is an issue I believe.
I have tried to change the archive path to a different path other than the default location, but the result is the same, I am still not able to any archives in the archive manager.

I can successfully archive my app using VS 2022 17.9.6 and it is shown as expected. You can try to upgrade your VS to the latest version to see if it works. Also, you can report the issue via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn.
Alternatively, you can still publish the app via command line, see Publish an Android app using the command line and Publish an iOS app using the command line.
BTW, .NET 6 is an old version for now, consider using .NET 8.

Hi Alexander May, Thank you for your response. I am successfully able to archive in the version 17.9.6 and the version that I have mentioned[17.7.6]. The problem that I am facing is that my archives are not being shown in the archive manager and due to this I am not able to distribute the application and give test release of the same. So is there settings that I need to do so that my archives will be shown in the archive manager?

@SuhasMR Have you followed the steps in docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-google-play?view=net-maui-8.0#distribute-your-app-through-google-play-console? 2. Looks like the .aab file is generated but not shown in the Archive Manager, you can refer to this simailar thread.

@Alexander May, I appreciate your suggestion. I'm encountering a problem while following the link for deploying and distributing the MAUI application. Specifically, steps 3 and 4 are where I'm running into issues. When I click on publish, the Visual Studio UI is completely blank, and I don't see the archive process happening. I've noticed a workaround mentioned in the second thread, which might be helpful, but it doesn't seem to address the exact issue I've described. Any additional suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

@SuhasMR Thanks for your update. If that still doesn't work, consider publishing the app via command line as I described in the answer.

@Alexander May, I appreciate the suggestions you provided. However, I'm still facing the issue of being unable to view any of my archives or the archive process inside the archive manager in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.9.6. It would be beneficial if you could provide a precise solution to this problem.

As I said before,  you can How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn. or publish via command line.

I resolved this problem:

Go to this path:
C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore


Here you can find your key—but if you have more .keystore files in one folder, the button won’t work;

I solved it by deleting the extraneous .keystore files.
